# show form errors using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

would like to show all errors on the right of a form when user makes input error.
Example if user enters incorrect e-mail format. I have created the div but I am not able to correctly display the errors and remove them as soon as the user corrects the input. Till now I am just highlighting the textbox using the error id.

jquery:

```
    var form = $("#contact_form");
var name = $("#name");
var nameInfo = $("#nameInfo");
var email = $("#email");
var emailInfo = $("#emailInfo");
var message = $("#message");
var messageInfo = $("#messageInfo");
var note = $("#note");

name.blur(validateName);
email.blur(validateEmail);
message.blur(validateMessage);


form.submit(function(){
    if(validateName() & validateEmail() & validateMessage()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});


function validateName(){
    if(name.val().length < 5){  
        name.addClass("error");
        return false;

    }else{

        name.removeClass("error");
        return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried any form validator plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use like this..

```
function validateName(){
    if(name.val().length < 5){  
        $("#nameError").html("Name should contain atleast 5 characters");
        name.addClass("error");
        return false;

    }else{
        $("#nameError").html("");
        name.removeClass("error");
        return true;

    }
```

}

nameError is an ID of the DIV you have created to show the error..

On name field keyDown event, just clear the error msg like this..

```
$("#nameError").html("");
```

Comment: you gave me the idea that I can create a separate div for each error next to each textbox and fill it up or remove it as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

i recommened you to use plugins rather that creating your own...

[jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

all the things that you wanted in your form is already done ... easy to use and modify..

Comment: links for the tutorial..http://www.jquery4u.com/forms/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/